# Scraping MSN News with Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm currently attempting to scrape MSN News with scrapy and am having some difficulties with getting the proper response from the browser when inside the scrapy shell.

when I go to https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/world in my browser, I see this:[image: Screenshot of what the page is supposed to look like]
which is perfect because that's what the page is supposed to look like, but when I run the command `scrapy shell https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/world` and then `view(response)` this is what I see instead.
[image: Screenshot of incorrect response]

I've tried disabling javascript to see if maybe the content was being loaded with ajax and that's why it wasn't working, but all that did was stop the thumbnails from loading. Anybody know why it's behaving this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website definitely has a lot of javascript running. How you should approach this is with disabling javascript in one instance and having a normal instance on the side.
Then you can dig around and compare, i.e. find thumbnail id and search it no-javascript source - it's probably somewhere in a json or a javascript variable.

[This is what scrapy sees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK9yM.png) with javascript disabled.
You can see that article names and short descriptions are there. If you inspect the title you can even see that there's a link to thumbnail as well!

```
articles = response.xpath("//li[@data-m]/a[@aria-label]")
for article in articles: 
    # thumbnail
    response.xpath('img/@data-src').extract_first()
    # '{"default":"//img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/tenant/amp/entityid/AAp0iW6.img?h=414&w=624&m=6&q=60&u=t&o=t&l=f&f=jpg&x=1280&y=688"}'
    # title 
    article.xpath("@aria-label").extract_first()
    # 'north korea can hit most of united states: u.s. officials provided by reuters'
    # description
    article.xpath("/img/@alt").extract_first()
    # This Friday, July 28, 2017, photo distributed by the Nort...
```

Comment: I'm not sure how disabling javascript got you the result you showed in that picture, when I disable javascript through chrome this is what I see: [link](https://imagebin.ca/v/3VOUoErN9dgo)

Comment: Yeah, `articles` is just a blank array, scrapy is still only getting the webpage that I showed a screenshot of in the question

Comment: @jason weird, can you post your `settings.py` or make sure `USER_AGENT` setting is set to something that looks like a browser? By default scrapy identifies itself as `scrapy <version>` so msn might just block you. e.g. try `USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0'`

Comment: Does MSN has copyrights when get news from other magazines?